# Talend- How to replace string from 'MATCHING' column to 'contactFirstName' column

Tags: java, talend, talend-mdm

I have a very tricky situation and have yet to come up with my own solution using Talend. I have an input MySql that has a number of columns and need to copy first string from MATCHING column to contactFirstName column when VALUE column contains 1;1;1

i am using tjavarow component.

Required description:
[image: Click here for required description]

Batch design:
[image: Click here for batch design]

Comment: Can you explain the requirment clearly?

Comment: Hi, Pradeep Gowtham I want to replace string from Matching Column to contactFirstName when the value column contains 1;1;1 How i can write logic in tjavarow component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple tMap, use the following expression for contactFirstname field in the output flow:
`row46.VALUE.equals("1;1;1") ? row46.MATCHING.replaceAll(";.*$", "") : row46.contactFirstname`

Here is a capture of the tMap I use for testing:
[image]

Hope this helps.
TRF

Answer (score 0):

You could use a specific flow in your tMap and filter it by the column which contains 1;1;1. Then, you could replace value from contactFirstName in your tMap.
The two flows go in database or memory. You could continue your process by using OnSubJobOk

Comment: Hi,Damien Marzlin Thanks for reply can you explain how i can apply filter in tMap which contain 1;1;1

Comment: Follow this [link](https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-tmap-component-joins.html)